# Possíveis causas para um session leak

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

Através de uma ferramenta de monitoramento, estou observando que minha aplicação possui um leak de sessão de usuário considerável. A cada dia, cerca de mil sessões de usuário são criadas, sem nenhuma ser destruída. Para tirar as sessões da memória, é necessário reiniciar o servidor de aplicação.

Além do timeout da session poder não estar definido, o que mais poderia causar um session leak?

Comment: Será que você está guardando um instância de Session em algum atributo estático? Isso faria com que o objeto Session de cada sessão não seja coletado.

Comment: Você já tentou colocar um `HttpSessionListener` com logs para ver se o método `sessionDestroyed` é chamado?

Comment: Verificarei estas possibilidades e retornarei. Contudo, o ideal como resposta seria ter as principais causas de um session leak. Isto porque, por ser uma aplicação muito antiga, a possibilidade de ser mais de um problema é muito grande.

Comment: Você sabe que tipo de aplicação está publicada no seu jboss? JSF 1.2, JSP, JSF 2.0? As vezes EJB's com ciclo de vida mal definidos podem causar esse tipo de problema.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck, esta plicação em especifico está publicada com JSF 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

O que pode causar este tipo de problema em aplicações JSF é o seguinte:

- **ManagedBeans** com ciclo de vida definidos como **ApplicationScope** ou **SessionScoped** que não são devidamente tratados.
- **PhaseListener** mal escritos que gravam muitas coisas na sessão e não retiram.

Geralmente este tipo de problema é de **programação** e não da **tecnologia**. Sugiro que revise o código da aplicação.